# How to see for which values a matrix loses rank?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm using Matlab and I have the following matrix:

[image]

where c2 mens cos(q2), c23 means cos(q2+q3), c234 means cos(q2+q3+q4) and analogously: s2 means sin(q2), s23 means sin(q2+q3), s234 means sin(q2+q3+q4)

Is there a way to see for which values of q2, q3 and q4 the matrix loses rank?

Comment: Try to do Gaussian elimination for your matrix, and extract your pivots, see the values which make your pivots zero depending on q2, q3, and q4 values.

Comment: Is there some command in Matlab that allows to do that?

Comment: rank(A) gives the rank of constant fixed array, but it will not work directly in your case, because there maybe infinite solutions for q2, q3, q4, you know that sin and cos are periodic, that means your solutions also will be repetitive and infinite.